# Too many connections using c3p0 and hibernate in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm using c3p0 for my connection pooling. I've configured min connections as 100 and max size as 2000. I'm just writing a simple insert program to check how many connections are active in workbench. But, I'm getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:650)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1808)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
```

My Hibernate.cfg.xml is as follows

```
<!-- c3p0 Connection pool config -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">2000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
```

My Java program is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Transaction tx = null;
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    System.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck", "true");
    Employee e = new Employee(2,"Richard");
    session.save(e);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);

    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("Great! Student was saved");

}
```

It works fine when the min size is 5 and max size is 20. Do I need to do any changes in MySQL workbench?

Comment: I really think 2000 is too many for any database and any connection pool to reasonably deal with. Why don't you stick to maximum 20, or perhaps even 50 or 100.

Comment: Because my DB can have max up to 6000 connections. My application would be having that number users

Comment: 6000 users could happily share 20 connections. It's likely each user only requires a connection for a fraction of the time they are logged in.

Comment: @Lance Java Oh then my understanding should be wrong. I was assuming that 6000 users = 6000 connections. But ideally they would be online. Do you still think that it won't make any difference? If the users would be doing some events(transactions) ?

Comment: @Syed Yes, your understanding is wrong. There's no such pattern as "connection per user" with connection pools. The whole idea of pooling is to share the objects. They won't be using the connections 100% of the time anyway.

Comment: If this is a web application, it's likely each user only requires a connection during a request/response (or even less if you have caching). The rest of the time they are just sitting looking at a static page until they fire another request

Comment: The whole idea of a connection pool is that connections are "borrowed" and then returned to the pool. Try with 100 max and see how you go.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your info.

Comment: @vikingsteve With 5 as min and 100 as max even this is working fine.

Comment: @LanceJava, in that case what would be ideal number for min and max if I'm going to have 6000-8000 users for my web application? I need to add few more, because tomorrow there is a chance of increased users.

Comment: @LanceJava When I run as Java application, why there are 5 number of connections which is shown in client connections in MySQL workbench, when I've set min as 5 and Max as 100? It would be only one connection, right?

Comment: No, you've set min to 5. So there are always 5 open connections which may scale up to 100 as needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole purpose of a database connection pool (like `c3p0`) is to optimise the use of resources versus the database.

If you had 6000 users with 6000 connections, you would quickly exhaust the available connections and errors would result.

Instead, a connection pool allows your application to "borrow" database connections from the pool, and return them after use.

So even though you have potentially 6000 users, the moments of time when multiple users are doing operations that operate versus the database concurrently *at that moment in time* would be a small fraction of that.

I would suggest to try this as a more reasonable value:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
```

After setting it up like this, I would run the application and watch the number of connections versus the database. If the 100 connections are at any time exhausted, you could look at tuning it upwards.

But I suspect that 100 concurrent connections will be enough - remember that they are "borrowed" from the c3p0 connection pool.

Documentation: [What is c3p0? (connection pooling)](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#basics)

Comment: Awesome explanation. 100 connections should be fine even if I have 10000 concurrent users ideally? Right?

Comment: Also what would be the max number of connections, if the users are around 1 Lakh? How should I calculate? Any formula do I need to observe?

Comment: The number of connections depends very much on the behaviour of the application though for 10000 users I would try initially with 100 max_size and increase to 200 if that's not enough. There is no real "forumla" here - it's just a matter of testing it under realistc load conditions - if not in your production environment then in a QA environment, or you could even use custom load testing tools

Comment: @Syed, as vikingsteve said, it depends on the application. Also worth mentioning, having more than the 'optimal' number of connection will slow down your application. Processing 1 transaction in serial is faster than processing 100 transaction in parallel (computer science 101). HikariCP documented a great explaining here https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing